# PHP Select from mysql not working

Tags: php, mysql

What's wrong with this code? I have tried everything to try to fix it.

```
$sql9 = "SELECT * FROM like WHERE postid='$pid' AND userid='$userid'";
$result9=mysql_query($sql9);

if($result9){
echo "It worked!";
}
```

Comment: There's no way to know. There are haldf a dozen reasons, all related to code you haven't posted.

Comment: `LIKE` is a [MySQL reserved keyword](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) You need to quote it with backticks.

Comment: ...and that one! Good catch @MichaelBerkowski

Comment: And I'm 100% sure all the other code is correct

Comment: May as well use `to` and `from` `while` you're at it. (*Just in `case` you `drop` `in` `and` `leave`*)

Comment: [Hello Bobby](http://xkcd.org/327)!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your table name is a [**reserved word**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) you have to use back-tick around it:

```
SELECT * FROM `like` WHERE postid='$pid' AND userid='$userid'
```

Also you should avoid using `mysql_*` which is a deprecated library and use MySQLi or PDO with prepared statements to avoid SQL Injections.

Here is a sample using PDO:

```
$sql = "SELECT * 
          FROM `like` 
         WHERE postid = :postId AND 
               userid = :userId";
$result = $con->prepare($sql);
$result->bindParam(':postId', $pid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$result->bindParam(':userId', $userid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$result->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to enclose like with quotes , because like is a reserved keyword of mysql . so mysql will treat it as LIKE clause .
the query should be as shown below .

```
$sql9 = "SELECT * FROM `like` WHERE postid='$pid' AND userid='$userid'";
$result9=mysql_query($sql9);

if($result9){
echo "It worked!";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can not use any keyword as table. Try using some other name of your table.